# How does node.js know express.js location

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mean-stack, requirements

How does my node.js server know how to find the express.js file?

In my server.js file I have a requirement for `express`:

```
var express        = require('express');
var app            = express();
```

My server.js file is in the `app` folder while express.js is in the `app\node_modules\express\lib` folder:

[image: Server.js File]

express.js is here in the `lib` directory

[image: Express.js File]

Does node.js automatically know to look in `node_modules` for dependencies? There is no direct enumeration of the path anywhere - I don't see it in the code.

This is [a sample project from scotch.io](https://scotch.io/tutorials/setting-up-a-mean-stack-single-page-application) and I'm trying to pick it apart and learn. I'm pretty new to the MEAN stack and I'm trying to understand this at a basic level.

FYI this is node v 4.5.0

Comment: "Does node.js automatically know to look in `node_modules` for dependencies?" [Yes.](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders)

Comment: @Mike C Ok - and it knows that `express.js` is going to be in `node_modules\express\lib`? May be an obvious question as well. I just hate taking things for granted :D

Comment: Yup! Because [it's specified in Express's `package.json`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules).

Comment: And Express has an `index.js` file *(at least it used to)*, that does `module.exports = require('./lib/express');`

Comment: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2169-where-does-node-js-and-require-look-for-modules.htm

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together

Comment: @MikeC I actually don't have a path specified in my `package.json` file

Comment: @adeneo Thank you for the blog link! That explains it quite clearly.

Comment: @Shrout1 I didn't say *you* did. I said Express did. Each package has their own `package.json` file.

Comment: @MikeC Ah I see this now; slowly I read the words on the page lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments already cover the main answer, but I'll try to break it out here for a slightly more complete overview of the subject (not all encompassing). The short version is that node looks in node's core (built in) packages, then your project's `node_modules` path for modules (packages, but we generally `require` modules) matching the name. [1](https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/packages)

#### Package Installation, Saving, and Location

Node uses `npm` to install dependencies, which can be either a "dependency" or "devDependency"; the latter is used for development concerns that shouldn't be required for just normally using the module. We save these to our project's `package.json` using the flag `--save` or `--save-dev` (such as `npm install express --save`). [2](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

The `package.json` file is what sits at the root of your project tree (the project's folder/directory) and contains the dependency information, along with other information. [3](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) This is defines a "package". When a person publishes a package to [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/), the (default) registry for packages to install via `npm`, they should include a well formed `package.json` which lists its own dependencies, files to include, and what is the "main" file to start with, should it be used in a `require` statement.

The dependencies you install by running `npm install` after cloning down the project's repository, will install the packages specified in the `package.json`, into the `node_modules` path in the root of your project (where you should be running the install command from).

Side Note

After checking [the GitHub repo](https://github.com/scotch-io/starter-node-angular) listed by the article you referenced, you appear to have created each of the files inside the `app/` directory.

#### Require-ing

The use of a `require` statement in node is in the style of [CommonJS](http://www.commonjs.org/) and for node, looks first (after core packages) in the `node_modules/` path or, if you specify a relative path to a folder or file, you can get it directly. Path relative means that it starts with `./` for a prefix to the current working directory (that the file is executing from), `../` for the directory above the current one, etc. There are other ways of handling paths, such as as the `path` module that is built into node [4](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html). For example, the following are valid:

- `require('./some-other.js')` require in that file's `module.exports`, from the `some-other.js` file [5](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports), in the current, relative path
- `require('./some.json')` will bring in JSON formatted content from a `.json` file [6](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2908-you-can-use-require-to-load-json-javascript-object-notation-files-in-node-js.htm), in the current, relative path
- `require('./routes')` will/can also bring in exported content from the `routes/` path (directory), which will by default start with the directory's `index.js`, should it exist [7](https://github.com/scotch-io/starter-node-angular/blob/964c3712bdeabc6a60ce495576222ca85fb6483f/server.js#L24-L25)

That last method is a nice way to be able to bring in a more complex requirement, without keeping everything in a single, overly busy file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am far less mystified than before.

Comment: My pleasure. It's certainly an interesting thing to wrap one's head around, especially as node and ES2015(/ES6) differ in import methodology.

Comment: "The use of a require statement in node is in the style of CommonJS and for node, looks first in the `node_modules/`" is wrong. Core modules are searched first before `node_modules` folder. The order becomes important when the module can be found in more than one location.

Comment: @wiseOne Good note re: core vs package modules. I see you added an answer that illustrates the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider the possible sources of modules:

- **Core modules** provided by Node.js.
- **Package modules** from doing `npm install`. These modules are stored in `node_modules` folder which is usually located in the root of the project.
- **Modules in any other location** in your project (Usually modules created by you)

If you require modules without any prefix e.g `require('a_module')`, the ***core modules* are searched first**, If it's not found, the *package modules* are searched next. [See the Node.js docs here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_accessing_the_main_module)

If you require modules with prefix `/` or `./`, e.g `require('/another_module')` , `require(./another_module)`, `another_module` is considered relative to the location of the requiring file. This is how you would require *modules in any other location*.

Check [Node.js modules docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) for further reading.